# How to look up an Azure Active Directory record for a give object_id GUID

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I need to look up a user record from the Azure Active Directory corresponding to the Object ID record. I am not sure how to do it. Any example in Powershell, or Azure CLI, or C# would be helpful.

Thanks.
Bharat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below [power shell command](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) you can lookup users information based on the Object Id

Install the AzureAD module. Run the command to connect to your AzureAD: Connect-AzureAD

`Get-AzureADUser -objectID 'object ID'`

Another ways id you can try with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Query:  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'ObjectID'`

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell it would be

```
C:\>Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "<Object ID>"
```